# Workspace switching indicator sometimes appears when switching windows on the same workspace in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

After I enable workspace switcher, assume there's multiple windows open on one workspace.

Sometimes when I switch back and forth between those open windows, it will randomly trigger the switching workspace indicator (the center thing when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrowkey</kbd> to switch workspace).

It feels like those windows had randomly jumped to other workspace when not in use. But this does not occur when you turn off workspace.

Any fix for this?